# Vue-simple-suggest casting v-model as null when loading data from vuex

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-simple-suggest

We are using Vue-Simple-Suggest in a v-for loop, to build an array of objects.

When we select an item, VSS updates the array and casts v-model correctly, which looks like

```
[ { name: 'add_tag', value: { id: 1, name: 'tag_name' } } , ... ]
```

But when we try to load the data again, v-model is cast to `null`

Replacing v-model with `:value="item.value"` gives us the correct display data, but we loose reactivity and the full nested object that we require.

This issue seems to be referenced on [github](https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest/pull/186)

Can anyone offer a word of advice?